# Resize GD Generated Image But Failed

Tags: php, gd

I have this code and it generates barcode on the screen. but it's too small to print. So, I want to scale the size, but why the `$thumb` image doesn't show on the screen? only $image shows up (the original image). what did I miss here? thank you

```
<?php
    //-- bunch of codes here --
    //-- then generate image -- 

    // Draw barcode to the screen
    header ('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);

    // Then resize it
    // Get new sizes
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
    $newwidth = $width * 2;
    $newheight = $height * 2;

    // Resize
    imagecopyresized($thumb, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    // Output and free memory
    header ('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($thumb);
    imagedestroy($thumb);
?>
```

Comment: you call `imagedestroy( $image )` and proceed to try to get properties of `$image`

Comment: @RamRaider : removing `imagedestroy($image);` still doesn't change the result, bro

Comment: Apart from destroying `$image` before you're trying to get it's height and width, you're outputting `$image` and later outputting `$thumb`. Choose one to show, not both in the same file as that will not work.

Comment: I don't believe that `getimagesize( $image )` will actually get the dimensions of the image as at his point you have sent the output to the browser and also $image is a resource and not a string path

Comment: also, where is $thumb initially defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst not having all the code to work with I emulated parts - the end result is a new image that is twice the size of the original. The main thing was not sending the headers initially but instead saving the resultant image to a temp file and then working with that.

```
<?php
    //-- bunch of codes here --
    //-- then generate image -- 


    /* You will already have a resource $image, this emulates that $image so you do not need this line */
    $image=imagecreatefrompng( 'c:/wwwroot/images/maintenance.png' );



    /* define name for temp file */
    $tmpimgpath=tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'img' );

    /* do not send headers here but save as a temp file */
    imagepng( $image, $tmpimgpath );


    // Then resize it, Get new sizes ( using the temp file )
    list( $width, $height ) = getimagesize( $tmpimgpath );
    $newwidth = $width * 2;
    $newheight = $height * 2;

    /* If $thumb is defined outwith the code you posted then you do not need this line either  */
    $thumb=imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );

    // Resize
    imagecopyresized( $thumb, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );

    // Output and free memory
    header ('Content-type: image/png');
    @imagedestroy( $image );
    @imagepng( $thumb );
    @imagedestroy( $thumb );
    @unlink( $tmpimgpath );
?>
```